Query Metadata from Knowledge or Data Sources in Copilot Studio
Is it possible to say something like "Show me files with X property set to Y"? I've tried using this query with the default create generative answers node with some of my Sharepoint sites, but haven't been able to get any results. I've also tried creating an adaptive card that stores that stores the aforementioned X and Y input and sends them to a Power Automate action that retrieves the links to all of the files that match it, but it doesn't seem like I can go any further with having the links to the files that match the search criteria.
